# Primitives and Objects

Tags: javascript

Definitive JavaScript by David Flanagan makes a distinction between Objects and Primitives.

He defines the primitives as Number, String, Boolean, Null, and Undefined, as does the standard.

However, would it be more accurate to define a primitive, as subset of object, i.e. to call them Primitive Objects.

Because they have their own methods and are complex entities.

**Actual Question**

Would Primitive Object be more accurate than Object when defining String, Boolean, and Number?

Comment: By the way, where were you *told everything in JavaScript was an object*?

Comment: ...I think the person, meant compared to other languages, conceptually, there are more objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Objects and primitives are distinct:

```
typeof 42 === "number"             
typeof new Number(42) === "object"
new Number(42) !== 42
```

However, when necessary, primitives are automatically wrapped by temporary objects, which can be [automatically converted back into primitives](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf):

```
(42).toString() === "42"
new Number(42) == 42
new Number(42) + 1 === 43
```

Especially in the context of the Java and C# programming languages, this sort of behavior is called [autoboxing](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoboxing). As wrapper objects have some confusing characteristics, for example:

```
Boolean(new Boolean(false)) === true
```

it is good practice to [avoid intentionally storing them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369220/why-should-you-not-use-number-as-a-constructor) in variables and instead use primitives whenever possible.

Comment: i see your point and i don't disagree...but it is untestable...you can't show that a primitive will break if you try and treat it like an object as it will "autobox" before you can.  in its primitive state, you have to rely on the typeof operator to tell you this, but we don't know how typeof is implemented.

Comment: We also know `typeof` is wrong [in some cases](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:typeof_null).

Comment: @kojiro: I considered mentioning the `typeof null` quirk; however, I decided to omit it as beside the point.

Comment: @PleaseStand is it beside the point, though? I considered that `typeof` may be returning the *boxed* value of `null`. `typeof Object(null) === typeof null`.

Answer (score 2):

It's not about semantics, look:

```
var threePrimitive = 3;
var threeObject = new Number(3);

threePrimitive.toFixed(2); // 3.00
threeObject.toFixed(2); // 3.00

threePrimitive.foo = true
threeObject.foo = true;
threePrimitive.foo; // undefined
threeObject.foo; // true
```

Primitives are wrapped in objects when you try to call a method on them, but after initial use the object is thrown away.

---

As for how this is stated in the specification, I'm not 100% sure, but here is what I think (based on the [tips left by Bergi in one of his answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13036273/825789). Section [11.2.1](http://es5.github.com/#x11.2.1) states that the accessor properties should be evaluated as follows:

> 1. Let baseReference be the result of evaluating MemberExpression.
> 2. Let baseValue be `GetValue`(*baseReference*).
>
> (...)

Then in [8.7.1](http://es5.github.com/#x8.7.1) we see the following:

> The following [[Get]] internal method is used by GetValue when *V* is a
>   property reference with a primitive *base* value. It is called using
>   base as its `this` value and with property *P* as its argument. The
>   following steps are taken:
>
> 1. Let O be ToObject(base).
> 2. Let desc be the result of calling the
>      [[GetProperty]] internal method of O with property name P.
> 3. If desc is
>      undefined, return undefined.
> 4. If IsDataDescriptor(desc) is true, return
>      desc.[[Value]].
> 5. Otherwise, IsAccessorDescriptor(desc) must be true so,
> 6. let getter be desc.[[Get]]. If getter is undefined, return undefined.
> 7. Return the result calling the [[Call]] internal method of getter
>      providing base as the this value and providing no arguments.
>
> NOTE The
>   object that may be created in step 1 is not accessible outside of the
>   above method. An implementation might choose to avoid the actual
>   creation of the object. The only situation where such an actual
>   property access that uses this internal method can have visible effect
>   is when it invokes an accessor function.

Comment: It's *entirely* a question about semantics. Your answer just happens to be *No, there is a difference between an Object Primitive and a Primitive*.

Comment: Look at the last example: if you try to add a property to a primitive, you lose it! So we can't say it always behave like an object.

Comment: Page 31 of ES5 (http://www.ecmascript.org/) - `―primitive‖ means Undefined, Null, Boolean, String, or Number.`

Comment: @bfavaretto Your comment makes it sound like you think I disagree, but I think we're talking about orthogonal subjects. I see your proof that `threePrimitive` and `threeObject` are different, but if the question was "Would *Primitive Object* [carry a] more accurate [meaning] then[sic] *Object*…?" then it's a *semantic* question, because it's about the meaning of words.

Comment: @Hiro Those are the primitive *types* of the language, yes. `3` is a primitive *value* of the type `Number`. But it's not an object (not and `instanceof Object`).

Comment: Distinction between primitive values and built in types - `A primitive value is a member of one of the following built-in types: Undefined, Null, Boolean, Number, and String;` - page 2

Comment: @kojiro You're right, I misinterpreted you when I added that reply. And you're right too about the semantics. The question is asking which would be the better term, but the fact is nothing will be 100% accurate unless we stick to the terms used in the language specification (which are rarely the most explanatory ones for those who are not used to the specs).

Comment: and also interesting p31 - `―primitive‖ means Undefined, Null, Boolean, String, or Number.`

Comment: primitive types ( or objects have you ) hold primitive values - this is inline with spec.

Comment: @Hiro I'll try to add my understanding on how it works according to the specification. Kojiro was right from the start by stating this is a semantic discussion. And, as such, I'm not sure how constructive it is, since, as I said above, "nothing will be 100% accurate unless we stick to the terms used in the language specification".

Comment: @Hiro I've seen your updates (btw, was the downvote from you?). The answer to your actual question is no, "primitive objects" is not more accurate. They're not objects, they're at a lower level (the lowest in the language).

Answer (score 1):

> Would Primitive Object be more accurate then Object when defining
>   String, Boolean, and Number?

*Please note that I'm not saying that numbers are not objects here, I'm pointing out that it **appears** ambiguous. This is the kind of thing that confuses JavaScript newcomers.*

The distinction is mostly academic, but there is one case where it seems ambiguous: literals represent primitive objects except when the literal appears to represent a number. You can't apply a method directly to a literal integer* symbol:

```
1.toString();
SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal
```

…but you can apply methods of Numbers:

```
Number(1).toString();
'1'
```

…and a name that contains a number is a Number:

```
x = 4;
x.toString();
'4'
```

I think this is actually a parsing problem, but I don't really know why the parser can't tell that `1` is a Number as easily as it can tell that "abc" is a String. I suppose it has to do with the semantic ambiguity of the `.` symbol. (Is it a decimal point or a method operator?)

*JavaScript doesn't actually have integers. I just mean a symbol that consists entirely of `[0-9]+`.

Comment: So my supposition was right, then. Still, there's no compelling reason why the tokenizer couldn't figure this out. (Especially since ECMA doesn't allow method names to begin with a decimal number.)

Comment: @Zeta: `1..toString()` :-P

Comment: It's not academic, primitives are not objects! But they get wrapped when necessary. You can't do `1.toString()` for a different reason (the dot is interpreted as the decimal point), but you can use `1..toString()`.

Comment: "note that I'm not saying that numbers are not objects here" -- I am. So I'm not one of those confirming your supposition. Neither I'm hitting you over the head (if you feel I am, I apologize, it was not my intention).

Comment: Personally I think these comments are worth more than my answer, which @bfavaretto demonstrated is wrong. (Although I stand by the meta-analysis that this question is mostly academic and entirely a semantic one.) Thus I don't want to delete this answer or change it to destroy the context of the comments. So I've changed it to CW.

Comment: From what I see, it is not just semantics as I originally guessed at (and if bfavaretto is correct ) then a primitive is distinct from an object.